# Expression to Count Applications for each store

Tags: expression, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I'm building a report in Report Builder. I'm trying to count the number of applications each store has received. THe expression I've written isn't breaking down by store though. For example, we've received two apps so far...one per store. But instead of showing one per store, it's showing both stores have two apps. How would I update this code to show this?

```
=COUNT(Fields!Branch_nbr.Value,Fields!STATUS.Value="A", "LoanAppsAll")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know the best option without seeing the report design and a sample of your data.

However, here's some ideas...

If "LoanAppsAll" is your dataset name then then that's the issue, you are asking SSRS to count everything with the scope of the entire dataset.
If the expression is within a rowgroup, and that rowgroup groups by store then you can probably just omit the scope parameter all together (remove `, "LoanAppsAll"` )

If the expression is in a child group who's parent group is grouped by store then you can specify the name of the rowgroup that groups by store as your scope name.

For example if you had 3 nested row groups, grouped by say Country then Store then SalesPerson and the row groups were named rgCountry, rgStore and rgSalesPerson respectively, then you would you `"rgStore"` as the scope name in place of `"LoanAppsAll"`

Hope that made sense, it's hard to be specific without more info.